# Getting the index of a view/viewgroup

Tags: android, xml, listview, radio-button, viewgroup

I have a customized list that is larger than 1 page on my device. My list has a customized list item XML that includes radio buttons. I wish to get the index of the list item when the radio button is selected. I've implemented onClickRadioButton(), but the index that I get back is incorrect as it always gets referenced to whatever is on the screen right now, i.e. if I scroll down such that list item #5 is at the top of the screen, then the index of list item #5 is 0.

My list XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Status" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:longClickable="true" >
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_mybutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My individual list item XML is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listName"
        android:maxLines="4" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="onClickRadioButton"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My onClickRadioButton() is as follows:

```
public void onClickRadioButton(View v) {
  View vMain = ((View)v.getParent());
  if (radioBut != null) {
    radioBut.setChecked(false);
  }
  radioBut = (RadioButton)v;
  if (radioBut.isChecked()) {
    listIndex = ((ViewGroup) vMain.getParent()).indexOfChild(vMain);
  } else {
    radioBut = null;
    listIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: indexOfChild is always related to the visible items. You need use onClick event from listView

Comment: Hi, how do I do that?

Comment: This may help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your `onclickRadioButton`,

```
    final int position = getListView().getPositionForView(v);
    if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        showMessage(getString(R.string.you_want_to_buy_format, CHEESES[position]));
    }
```

For more info, visit [this](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/) and check out "Getting the position of a View in a ListView" section.